# Slide Reverse Transitions, Vue Js

Tags: css, vue.js, css-transitions, vue-router

I'm developing a single page application / mobile app, with Vue.JS. I want a slide effect when changing the pages, and I can do it like this:

```
transition name="slide"
 router-view transition
transition
```

But I wanted the reverse effect of the slide when the user returns the page. In other words, when the user opens a new page, the page will come from the right, but when they go back, the page will come from the left.

There is a plugin for Vue router, called [`vue-router-transition`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-router-transition), but it does not work. It is out of date, it only works with very old versions of Vue.

Also there is a [tutorial on dynamic transitions](https://router.vuejs.org/en/advanced/transitions.html), but only works when it is parents routes, ex: `example.com/rota1/rota2/rota3`, which is not my case.

I thought of the following logic in the `before.each.router`, set the transition class (`slide-left` or `slide-right`) depending on whether the user clicked on a go back button.

The problem is that I do not know how to apply this logic in code. I would have to pass the value of a variable that is in `main.js` to `app.vue` and I do not know how to do this.

Answer (score 2):

A while ago I've used the `meta` object in `vue-router` and added a "fake" depth, because I haven't any children objects. If you use children, then go with this example: https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router/blob/dev/examples/transitions/app.js

```
export default () => {
  return [{
      meta: {
        depth: 0
      },
      path: '/home',
      component: Home
    },
    {
      meta: {
        depth: 1
      },
      path: '/about',
      component: About
    }]
}
```

Now you can check it by your own like this in your `App.vue`.

```
watch: {
  $route(to, from) {
    const toDepth = to.meta.depth || 0;
    const fromDepth = from.meta.depth || 0;

    this.transitionName = toDepth >= fromDepth ? 'slide-left' : 'slide-right';
  }
}
```

Comment: No. With my solution you decide it. You write the depth into your router object and its not detected by counting “/“.

Comment: it works, but I think it's not the best solution for a big project, it would make a mess, it's like using CSS's z-index to position many div.

Answer (score 2):

Hope this helps:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#demo',
  data: {
    slideTransition: 'slide-left',
    showChild: false,
  },
  watch: {
    showChild(value) {
      if (value) {
        this.setSlideTransition('slide-right');
      } else {
        this.setSlideTransition('slide-left');
      }
    },
  },
  methods: {
    setSlideTransition(slideDirection) {
      // Note: 300ms mentioned below is matching with css transition timing
      setTimeout(() => { this.slideTransition = slideDirection; }, 300);
    },
  },
});
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  color: #bdbdbd;
  background-color: #161616;
  font-family: Helvetica neue, roboto;
}

.container {
  width: 500px;
  background: #161616;
}

main {
  width: 60%;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #333;
}

aside {
  width: 40%;
  background-color: #555;
}

.container, main, .parent, .child, .content {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.parent {
  background-color: deepskyblue;
}

.child {
  background-color: deeppink;
}

.container, main, aside {
  position: relative;
  height: 199px;
}

.pin {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.pt-50 {
  padding-top: 50px;
}

/* transitions */
.fade-enter-active,
.fade-leave-active {
  transition-property: opacity;
  transition-duration: 0.25s;
}

.fade-enter-active {
  transition-delay: 0.25s;
}

.fade-enter,
.fade-leave-active {
  opacity: 0;
}

.slide-left-leave-active,
.slide-left-enter-active,
.slide-right-leave-active,
.slide-right-enter-active {
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.slide-left-enter {
  transform: translate(100%, 0);
}

.slide-left-leave-to {
  transform: translate(-100%, 0);
}

.slide-right-enter {
  transform: translate(-100%, 0);
}

.slide-right-leave-to {
  transform: translate(100%, 0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id="demo" class="container">
  <aside>
    <transition name="fade">
      <div class="pin parent" v-if="!showChild">
        <div>
          <h1>Parent</h1>
          <a href="#" @click="showChild = true">Go To Child</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </transition>
    <transition :name="slideTransition">
      <div class="pin child" v-if="showChild">
        <div>
          <h1>Child</h1>
          <a href="#" @click="showChild = false">Go To Parent</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </transition>        
  </aside>
  <main>
   <div>
    <h1>Main</h1>
    <transition name="fade">
      <div v-if="showChild" class="pin content pt-50" key="child">
        <h4>Child Content here</h4>
      </div>
      <div v-else="" class="pin content pt-50" key="parent">
        <h4>Parent Content here</h4>
      </div>
    </transition>
   </div>
  </main>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I see 2 options:

1. Store a variable in Vuex "transitionBack" and set it to true. Change the router-link to a `@click` method. In the method, first save the variable and then navigate to the link. Check that variable on your `beforeRouteUpdate(to, from, next)` method.
2. Implement some logic in your `beforeRouteUpdate(to, from, next)` method that will check on the name of the link (e.g. if you can only go "back" from a certain page, then keep a list of all these type of pages)